# Developer console not recognising startTest() and stopTest()

Tags: apex, developer-console, asynchronous-testing

I am creating an Apex class that uses the `@future` annotation to update Account records and this is my Account Processor:

```
public without sharing class AccountProcessor {
    
    @future
    public static void countContacts(List<Id> accountIds) {
    
        // Retrieve the Account records for the supplied Ids
        List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM Contacts) FROM Account 
                                  WHERE Id IN :accountIds];
                                
        // Update the field with the size of each Contact collection
        for (Account acc : accounts) {
            acc.Number_of_Contacts__c = acc.Contacts.size();
        }
        
        // Update the modified Account records
        update accounts;
    }
}
```

Then when I input my `AccountProcessorTest` I use this code:

```
@isTest
private class AccountProcessorTest {

    @isTest
    private static void countContactsTest() {
        
        // Load test data
        List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
        for (Integer i=0; i<300; i++) {
            accounts.add(new Account(Name='Test Account' + i));
        }
        insert accounts;
        
        List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
        List<Id> accountIds = new List<Id>();
        for (Account acc: accounts) {
            contacts.add(new Contact(FirstName=acc.Name, LastName='TestContact', AccountId=acc.Id));
            accountIds.add(acc.Id);
        }
        insert contacts;
        
        // Perform the test
        Test.startTest();
        AccountProcessor.countContacts(accountIds);
        Test.stopTest();
        
        // Check the result
        List<Account> accs = [SELECT Id, Number_of_Contacts__c FROM Account];
        for (Account acc : accs) {
            System.assertEquals(1, acc.Number_of_Contacts__c, 'ERROR: At least 1 Account record with incorrect Contact count');            
        }
    }
}
```

After doing this I get 2 problems saying `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void startTest() from the type test` as well as `Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void stopTest() from the type test`.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you happen to have a class named just simply `Test` in your org? If so, that'd shadow the methods that Salesforce provides in the `System.Test` class. Using the fully qualified class name, so `System.Test.startTest()`, would work if that's the case but that's mostly for confirming the issue. If that is the issue, the solution would be to rename/remove the custom `Test` apex class in your org.

Comment: Also, do note that directly accessing the Contacts like `acc.Contacts.size()` is potentially unsafe. If an Account has more than 200 Contacts related to it, you're liable to run into an error. The only completely safe way to deal with subqueries is by looping over the subquery results (even for something as simple as getting a record count). Nested loops are not inherently evil.

Comment: Upon checking my org there are no classes with the name Test

Answer (score -1):

Resolved the issue it had to do with the countContacts

Comment: So, what was the actual issue and how did you solve it? Don't be [like DenverCoder9](https://xkcd.com/979/)